# How to properly convert a df to time-series and clean it in the same pipeline?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, time-series, purrr

I am trying to convert a dataframe to time-series object (`ts`) and then clean the noise of those time-series by using a filter (`bkfilter()`: this filter cleans time-series noise), these tasks are intended to be applied by group (`decil` df column).

Here's my attempt:

```
library(dplyr)
library(mFilter)
library(purrr)

test <-  df  %>%
            ## nesting dataframe by group ##
             dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
             dplyr::nest_by(decil) %>%
  
            ## converting each nested tibble to time-series ##
            dplyr::summarise(data_ts = purrr::map(data, ts)) %>%
                      
            ## applying cleaning filter to each nested time-series tibble ##
            mFilter::bkfilter(data_ts, pl=6,pu=32,type="fixed",drift=FALSE) %>%
  
            ## unnest and ungroup tibbles to get a final df ##
            tidyr::unnest(decil) %>%
            dplyr::ungroup()
```

And the next error arises:

> Error in mFilter::bkfilter(., data_ts, pl = 6, pu = 32, type = "fixed",  :
> object 'data_ts' not found.

Expected Output could be a df/tibble composed by a group column (`decil`), a date column (`año`), and cleaned time-series columns (cleaned by `bkfilter()` function).

That looks like this:

```
#   año     decil       clean_val1  clean_val2
#   <fct>   <date>        <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 Decil 1 1992-01-01  0.286    0.308
# 2 Decil 1 1996-01-01 -0.299   -2.74 
# 3 Decil 1 1998-01-01  0.424   -0.117
# 4 Decil 1 2000-01-01  0.488    1.28 
# 5 Decil 1 2002-01-01 -0.00852 -0.591
# 6 Decil 1 2004-01-01  0.671    2.22 
# 7 Decil 1 2005-01-01  1.06    -1.23 
# 8 Decil 1 2006-01-01  0.242    2.91 
# 9 Decil 1 2008-01-01  0.0204   1.94 
#10 Decil 1 2010-01-01 -0.298   -1.71
```

### data

```
df <- structure(list(decil = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("Decil 1", "Decil 2", 
"Decil 3", "Decil 4", "Decil 5", "Decil 6", "Decil 7", "Decil 8", 
"Decil 9", "Decil 10"), class = "factor"), año = structure(c(8035, 
9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 
15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 
12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 
8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 
14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 
11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 
17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 
13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 
10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 
16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 
13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 
10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 
16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 
12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 
9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 
15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 
12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 
8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 
14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 
11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 
17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 
13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 
10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 
16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 
13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 
10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 
16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 
12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 
9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 
15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 
12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 17532
), class = "Date"), variable = c("Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el Poder Adquisitivo (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", "Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)", 
"Crecimiento en el PIB Real per Cápita (%)"), value = c(0.308138265449932, 
-2.73923609850588, -0.116791699821611, 1.276823919767, -0.591033604229833, 
2.217410209762, -1.22771361710334, 2.91323734975109, 1.9403678544531, 
-1.710307316049, 0.114882675671299, 1.31658931355581, 1.46477971543751, 
0.271712366085317, 0.274660079065288, -1.20391288467938, 0.221116802499613, 
1.68878772891571, -0.0553564396020631, 2.47304289689454, -1.49473828679342, 
2.06995781551323, 0.995111688295987, -1.23590101185821, -0.0513493069577327, 
1.57518955283768, 1.49952051319558, 0.569875774759632, 0.0595105282871455, 
-1.98229069194358, 0.692781223252039, 1.45357299983422, 0.274519154273341, 
2.50570229399105, -1.58798738651613, 1.8318771262172, 0.541185894582713, 
-1.09932567808292, 0.159443784781767, 1.38386952581564, 1.42469406477504, 
0.410413545862179, -0.144568025477976, -1.88765679042184, 1.01321912136977, 
1.16094403156238, 0.427582908849506, 2.59548917592467, -1.91921130444488, 
1.86512952445194, 0.0990294699338842, -0.837785709745078, 0.543096597486442, 
0.741481129770513, 1.29946597715581, 0.622336720429403, 0.139031953354982, 
-1.90241726271236, 0.690016525955506, 1.54716844723562, 0.256469067826587, 
2.46741215896569, -1.52082399890795, 1.46298279854535, -0.178133254716425, 
-0.570996073876508, 0.530083911456838, 0.771074074546392, 1.22148158785322, 
0.480369193797477, -0.0401792821387455, -2.1998371424533, 1.06632797701267, 
0.742663665613463, 0.534777779842798, 2.24439518748242, -1.19081274931006, 
1.26230193789639, -0.256049568632538, -0.54511282604089, 0.828289107854747, 
0.198585514462626, 1.12490515302622, 0.454776270025511, 0.308138951062849, 
-1.68702475271693, 0.963026950989102, 0.924694309980609, 0.0909783913993086, 
2.19423265975474, -1.04193226868249, 1.26951414528773, -0.599866837527287, 
-0.504144411887512, 1.2633719573124, -0.208565860801489, 1.28053568465138, 
0.223463615789722, 0.0762802869455859, -2.21763771759914, 1.08353667375486, 
1.27220562258605, -0.0199740141807546, 2.34686607111593, -1.01924956162359, 
0.996632035015618, -0.943588762041933, -0.311576607205403, 1.18147547163377, 
-0.283811580551448, 1.1151512141408, 0.256848322836834, -0.0557319323771243, 
-2.56639439214237, 1.09841238497413, 0.970528742740132, -0.041290083196072, 
2.89203820342315, -1.13995943017165, 1.0666144712339, -1.48427029516519, 
-0.237956102817481, 1.18845793975459, -0.0723117556104279, 0.578897782929168, 
0.310574312466805, 0.0420320020065887, -2.65571871864779, 1.08040626539541, 
0.501353172078248, 0.264579769939744, 3.45907008361297, -1.47337410644853, 
0.753187592344928, -1.67914957857585, -0.386430954714176, 1.18684061581655, 
-0.0837921856848724, 0.271367995890336, -0.244522199262534, 0.285801450939386, 
-0.299493284604054, 0.423776690674324, 0.48819479659131, -0.00851835182683933, 
0.670710736839509, 1.0584695348906, 0.241749748695944, 0.0203934290972816, 
-0.298146398803882, 0.454536882635523, 0.0317493839324935, 0.399645473642857, 
0.149656209777629, 0.285801450939386, -0.299493284604054, 0.423776690674324, 
0.48819479659131, -0.00851835182683933, 0.670710736839509, 1.0584695348906, 
0.241749748695944, 0.0203934290972816, -0.298146398803882, 0.454536882635523, 
0.0317493839324935, 0.399645473642857, 0.149656209777629, 0.285801450939386, 
-0.299493284604054, 0.423776690674324, 0.48819479659131, -0.00851835182683933, 
0.670710736839509, 1.0584695348906, 0.241749748695944, 0.0203934290972816, 
-0.298146398803882, 0.454536882635523, 0.0317493839324935, 0.399645473642857, 
0.149656209777629, 0.285801450939386, -0.299493284604054, 0.423776690674324, 
0.48819479659131, -0.00851835182683933, 0.670710736839509, 1.0584695348906, 
0.241749748695944, 0.0203934290972816, -0.298146398803882, 0.454536882635523, 
0.0317493839324935, 0.399645473642857, 0.149656209777629, 0.285801450939386, 
-0.299493284604054, 0.423776690674324, 0.48819479659131, -0.00851835182683933, 
0.670710736839509, 1.0584695348906, 0.241749748695944, 0.0203934290972816, 
-0.298146398803882, 0.454536882635523, 0.0317493839324935, 0.399645473642857, 
0.149656209777629, 0.285801450939386, -0.299493284604054, 0.423776690674324, 
0.48819479659131, -0.00851835182683933, 0.670710736839509, 1.0584695348906, 
0.241749748695944, 0.0203934290972816, -0.298146398803882, 0.454536882635523, 
0.0317493839324935, 0.399645473642857, 0.149656209777629, 0.285801450939386, 
-0.299493284604054, 0.423776690674324, 0.48819479659131, -0.00851835182683933, 
0.670710736839509, 1.0584695348906, 0.241749748695944, 0.0203934290972816, 
-0.298146398803882, 0.454536882635523, 0.0317493839324935, 0.399645473642857, 
0.149656209777629, 0.285801450939386, -0.299493284604054, 0.423776690674324, 
0.48819479659131, -0.00851835182683933, 0.670710736839509, 1.0584695348906, 
0.241749748695944, 0.0203934290972816, -0.298146398803882, 0.454536882635523, 
0.0317493839324935, 0.399645473642857, 0.149656209777629, 0.285801450939386, 
-0.299493284604054, 0.423776690674324, 0.48819479659131, -0.00851835182683933, 
0.670710736839509, 1.0584695348906, 0.241749748695944, 0.0203934290972816, 
-0.298146398803882, 0.454536882635523, 0.0317493839324935, 0.399645473642857, 
0.149656209777629, 0.285801450939386, -0.299493284604054, 0.423776690674324, 
0.48819479659131, -0.00851835182683933, 0.670710736839509, 1.0584695348906, 
0.241749748695944, 0.0203934290972816, -0.298146398803882, 0.454536882635523, 
0.0317493839324935, 0.399645473642857, 0.149656209777629)), row.names = c(NA, 
-280L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What am I missing? Is there any other simpler way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bkfilter requires regularly spaced data which you don't have so we use a loess smoother instead.  You may wish to try a different span parameter for loess but here we use the default.  Also since all the dates are all January 1st we simplify that column to just the year.   The data in the question has changed but the code below uses the original data shown in the Note at the end (except we only reproduce the first 42 rows to reduce the test data).

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(año) %>%
  mutate(decil = lubridate::year(decil), 
         val1 = fitted(loess(val1 ~ decil)),
         val2 = fitted(loess(val2 ~ decil))) %>%
  ungroup
```

or if you have many val columns:

```
df %>%
  group_by(año) %>%
  mutate(decil = lubridate::year(decil),
    across(starts_with("val"), ~ fitted(loess(. ~ decil)))) %>%
  ungroup
```

To create a regularly spaced series using loess use this instead:

```
result <- df %>%
  group_by(año) %>%
  mutate(decil = lubridate::year(decil)) %>%
  group_modify(~ {
    rng <- range(.x$decil)
    d <- data.frame(decil = rng[1]:rng[2])
    data.frame(d, 
      val1 = predict(loess(val1 ~ decil, .x), d),
      val2 = predict(loess(val2 ~ decil, .x), d))
   }) %>%
   ungroup
```

Regarding turning this into time series objects this code creates both zoo and ts objects:

```
library(zoo)

val1.z <- read.zoo(result[-4], split = "año", index = "decil")
val2.z <- read.zoo(result[-3], split = "año", index = "decil")

val1.ts <- as.ts(val1.z)
val2.ts <- as.ts(val2.z)
```

### Note

The data in the question was changed but the above used the original data of which the first 42 rows are:

```
df <- structure(list(año = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Decil 1", "Decil 2", "Decil 3", "Decil 4", 
"Decil 5", "Decil 6", "Decil 7", "Decil 8", "Decil 9", "Decil 10"
), class = "factor"), decil = structure(c(8035, 9496, 10227, 
10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 
16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 
13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 16071, 16801, 17532, 8035, 9496, 
10227, 10957, 11688, 12418, 12784, 13149, 13879, 14610, 15340, 
16071, 16801, 17532), class = "Date"), val1 = c(0.285801450939386, 
-0.299493284604054, 0.423776690674324, 0.48819479659131, -0.00851835182683933, 
0.670710736839509, 1.0584695348906, 0.241749748695944, 0.0203934290972816, 
-0.298146398803882, 0.454536882635523, 0.0317493839324935, 0.399645473642857, 
0.149656209777629, 0.285801450939386, -0.299493284604054, 0.423776690674324, 
0.48819479659131, -0.00851835182683933, 0.670710736839509, 1.0584695348906, 
0.241749748695944, 0.0203934290972816, -0.298146398803882, 0.454536882635523, 
0.0317493839324935, 0.399645473642857, 0.149656209777629, 0.285801450939386, 
-0.299493284604054, 0.423776690674324, 0.48819479659131, -0.00851835182683933, 
0.670710736839509, 1.0584695348906, 0.241749748695944, 0.0203934290972816, 
-0.298146398803882, 0.454536882635523, 0.0317493839324935, 0.399645473642857, 
0.149656209777629), val2 = c(0.308138265449932, -2.73923609850588, 
-0.116791699821611, 1.276823919767, -0.591033604229833, 2.217410209762, 
-1.22771361710334, 2.91323734975109, 1.9403678544531, -1.710307316049, 
0.114882675671299, 1.31658931355581, 1.46477971543751, 0.271712366085317, 
0.274660079065288, -1.20391288467938, 0.221116802499613, 1.68878772891571, 
-0.0553564396020631, 2.47304289689454, -1.49473828679342, 2.06995781551323, 
0.995111688295987, -1.23590101185821, -0.0513493069577327, 1.57518955283768, 
1.49952051319558, 0.569875774759632, 0.0595105282871455, -1.98229069194358, 
0.692781223252039, 1.45357299983422, 0.274519154273341, 2.50570229399105, 
-1.58798738651613, 1.8318771262172, 0.541185894582713, -1.09932567808292, 
0.159443784781767, 1.38386952581564, 1.42469406477504, 0.410413545862179
)), row.names = c(NA, -42L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```